# How build docker images from Github repo?

Tags: github

Build docker images from Github repo

I'm trying to build images.
I cloned the repository (github.com/microservices-demo/microservices-demo) from Github to my local computer (disk C).

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:6.17

ENV NODE_ENV "development"
ENV NODE_PATH "/usr/src/app/node_modules"

# Install base dependencies
RUN apk update
RUN apk add git python

# Prepare app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
VOLUME /tmp/specs

# Start the app
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/node_modules/dredd/bin/dredd"]
```

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apk add git python" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Comment: Can you provide the full log output? There must be more details somewhere about the error that happened when that line ran, and that log should have the information needed to figure this out.

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/Afrph4x6ChGTiQ this is terminal log from VS code

Comment: This log has a different error, where it's the `npm install` instruction that fails, and the `apk add git python` result is just reused from cache. Are you getting such errors every time you run? Does this app install and run outside Docker?